# Postfix and saslauthd on Debian Wheezy not working after upgrade

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, saslauthd

Since upgrading to Wheezy I've been unable to send emails via my own mail server which used to have a functioning combination of Dovecot, saslauthd and postfix using pam.

Now, running `testsaslauthd` as root worked fine:

```
$ sudo testsaslauthd -s smtp -u <myusername> -u <mypassword>
$ sudo testsaslauthd -s smtpd -u <myusername> -u <mypassword>
$ sudo testsaslauthd -u <myusername> -u <mypassword>
```

All gave

```
0: OK "Success."
```

Running as myself or with `sudo -u postfix`would however give me a permission denied error. After checking the permissions on `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/` and the files in there I decided to run `sudo usermod -a -G sasl postfix` which made `testsaslauthd` run fine for the `postfix` user as well.

However, I'm still getting these errors in `/var/log/mail.log`

```
postfix/smtpd[27652]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
warning: unknown[<redacted>]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
warning: unknown[<redacted>]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
lost connection after AUTH from unknown[<redacted>]
disconnect from unknown[<redacted>]
```

( is my client's IPv6 address, removed because it's irrelevant clutter)

`/var/run/saslauthd` is a symlink pointing at `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd` btw.

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error was in my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, adding the following line magically fixed everything:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

I could've sworn it was there before I upgraded…